# Is that possible in jwt-auth to use one token for two Models?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I use jwt-auth for authentication and i have two authenticatable models in my project "User" and "Company".
I have to different middlewares. one for "User" and one for "Company". and each model had its own token (saved in cookies).

This two model is related (user belongs to a company)

now i want to get a user and if the user belongs to Company, login the user as company too. it simple to do this, but i need to do this with **just one** token. because i want to use one request and one middleware.

Is there any way or method that i can set user token to company. instead of get new token from company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not proper way. `User` should be authenticated, and not the `Company`, but user `belongs to` company, so you can modify/access/change data, within that relationship.

IMO, you should go that path.

Comment: yeah i know what you say. if it was from scratch definitely i would do that. but now i have to change so many codes.
 And consider that the ```User``` ```belongs to many``` company so i have store current Company somewhere. and i could do that whit token.  but i think i have no choice and do what you said.

Comment: It would be easier to just make it this approach, than to create a new authenticator class, trust me.